# Adding textarea in form makes it loose responsive property in yahoo purecss

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, yui-pure-css

I was designing an simple form and I noticed That after adding rows and columns in `textarea` the form no longer show its responsive property.

After removing the `cols="80" rows="10"` from `textarea` I noticed that the form remains responsive until the size of the textares or simply saying the textarea is not showing any responsive property how can I fix this ?

My Page design can be viewed [**here**](http://jsbin.com/hanesovi/3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it of My own:
Adding this css property did the job.

```
textarea {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;

    min-height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;

    overflow: auto;
}
```